# Spring Integration Java DSL: How to run the integration flow in the JUnit?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to run the integrationFlow in the below JUnit class? Currently there comes the exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s). 0 request(s) executed.
```

because the integration flow is not started.

The JUnit class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
public class FlowTest {
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080/data"));

    final IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = f -> f
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/data", restTemplate).httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class));

    mockServer.verify();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just define a flow like that in a test method; the framework has to do a bunch of assembly behind the scenes.

Define the flow as a `@Bean` in a test `@Configuration` class.